# Matching Before Randomization in R

Tags: r, experiment-design, matching

I would like to divide 100 subjects into 50 matched pairs. Within each pair, I would like to randomize one subject into a treatment group and the other into a control group. I would like to match the 100 subjects on two covariates, one continuous (x1) and one categorical (x2).

Here's a recreation of the variables I am working with:

```
# Continuous Variable
set.seed(1) 
x1 <- rnorm(100, 42.8, 12.7) %>% round()

# Categorical Variable
x2 <- c("small", "medium", "large")
x2 <- sample(x2, 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.57, 0.18, 0.24))

# Data Frame
df = tibble(x1, x2)
```

I tried using the matching package `MatchIt` but the package requires a treatment variable (z) to calculate the propensity scores. I don't have a treatment variable Z. I would like to create a treatment variable Z using the matched pairs.

Comment: I actually think this is on-topic. OP is looking for a statistical technique to perform the type of matching he desires. The R code simple provides an illustration of the data. This is not a question about programming or debugging.

Comment: @Noah Thank you for that comment.  I agree and find the topic relevant and, as yet, not covered well on our site.  Unfortunately the accepted answer is purely software-oriented, indicating that this thread is off topic and virtually precluding contributions of any statistical interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MatchIt` performs bipartite matching, where individuals already exist within groups and you want to find appropriate pairs. What you want to perform is nonbipartite matching, which finds pairs among ungroups individuals. See [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/413640/how-to-form-groups-before-randomizing-the-treatment-assignment/414886#414886) for references. The R package `nbpMatching` performs this operation.

Comment: Hi Noah, nonbipartite matching was exactly what I was looking for. Nbp matching did the trick. Thank you!